# More documentation on stylesheets?

Tags: stylesheet, documentation, reference-request, guidelines

I am finding the "help" for manipulating stylesheets in Mathematica is limited.  I have a found a number of helpful tips in the documentation center and StackExchange, including help with understanding inheritace, functions, counters, environments.  This has a been great learning experience.  However, I find that my progress is now slow as I have many more detailed questions and only seem to find a few examples in the documentation center and tidbits in Stack Exchange.  Does anyone knows of a textbook that specifically covers the in's and out's of manipulating stylesheets in a more thorough and organized manner?  This would help me immensely as I build a stylesheet for a textbook.

Comment: +1, but it may be more productive in the end to organize those tidbits and ask specific questions here ...

Comment: Is this about notebook programming (as they are just notebooks at the end), a workflow with stylesheets, or about how a front end uses stylesheets?

Comment: This is true.  Yes.  I'm looking for "best practices" and "tips and tricks" for creating style sheets for a textbook.  I have been reverse engineering the stylesheet for a math textbook I found that was made with mathematica.  I have been working on it for a while and always running into road blocks on understanding how the author achieved certain features through stylesheets.

Comment: Yes, I think a deeper understanding of how style sheets and styles work would help immensely.  For me, the documentation center doesn't fulfill this desire.  There are so many nuances in typesetting for a math textbook, but was hoping that someone has some guidance on a textbook that works through more of the best practices and features that can be used in creating a math textbook.

Comment: At WTC2016 there was mention that better support for notebook stylesheet and slideshow template editing/authoring was coming.  No mention on which version.  I too have not been able to successfully create the simplest of slideshow template with corporate resources (logos, backgrounds, colours, ...).